# How to make scatter plot matrix in matlab with different colors in one plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, scatter, plotmatrix

In matlab *plotmatrix* can be used for displaying matrix of plots. Is it possible to have different colors in one plot? I have high dimensional data (e.g. 10 dimensions) and I want to display them using plot matrix. I want to use different colors for different clusters.

I want it look like this:

[image]

Also I want to assign color programatically i.e. to to have

```
colors=lines(numClusters);
```

and then for cluster i=1:n assign

```
'Color',colors(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

[gplotmatrix](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/gplotmatrix.html) command can be used for that

Comment: How to distinguish more than 7 groups?